# Unable to deploy AppEngine Go app with runtime 1.12 that uses external libraries

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-app-engine-go

I'm trying to migrate an old Google App Engine (standard environment) project written in Go to runtime 1.12. I haven't touched it since late 2017 and a lot seems to have changed since then. I've been able to sort some things out, but I fail to deploy the code since I have some external dependencies.

Relevant parts of the console output when trying to deploy

```
d:\src\go\src\data-axe>go env GOPATH
d:\src\go

d:\src\go\src\data-axe>gcloud app deploy --no-promote
...
Error type: BuildError.
Error message: 2019/09/27 19:10:09 Your app is not on your GOPATH, this build may fail.
2019/09/27 19:10:10 Building from Go source in /tmp/staging/srv, with main package at ./...
2019/09/27 19:10:10 Building /tmp/staging/srv, saving to /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start
2019/09/27 19:10:11 Wrote build output to /builder/outputs/output
2019/09/27 19:10:11 Failed to build app: Your app is not on your GOPATH, please move it there and try again.
...
 err=exit status 1, out=srv/main.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday" in any of:
...
```

As seen in the snippet above my GOPATH is set to `d:\src\go`, my app is in `d:\src\go\src\data-axe` and and Bluemonday that I'm using is in `d:\src\go\src\github.com\microcosm-cc\bluemonday` so to my best knowledge all of this is in my GOPATH.

The App Engine documentation for [specifying dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/specifying-dependencies) say

> If your application is in a directory on your GOPATH, App Engine analyzes, copies, and uploads your imports from GOPATH. This approach supports vendor directories.

There must be something I don't understand here. I have both my code and the library I use in my GOPATH but the App Engine doesn't seem to pick up and upload my import when I try to deploy.

The import in my main.go is using an absolute path as the documentation say it should:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday"
    "strings"
    "log"
    "os"
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit**

Full output of `go env`:

```
d:\src\go\src\data-axe>go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\niklas\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=d:\src\go
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=c:\go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\niklas\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build168636674=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Comment: if you're using go modules, you don't need to put your code inside $GOPATH (especially with same path as $GOROOT). Just make a `work/` directory somewhere. Or name it `projects/` .

Comment: Does the application build locally?  What's the output of `go env`?

Comment: @LaevusDexter, I'm not familiar with go modules so I'll have to read up on that and try that approach if I can't get this to work.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, the application builds and runs locally, I've updated the question with the full `go env` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem in two different ways.

The first was to copy my project outside of my $GOPATH and enable go modules like explained in [this simple guide](https://www.kablamo.com.au/blog/2018/12/10/just-tell-me-how-to-use-go-modules). When I did this I was able to successfully deploy my application including all it's dependencies.

I also manged to solve the problem without go modules. It turned out that it was not only my project that hadn't been touched in a very long time. My Google Cloud SDK was also severely outdated. After I updated it with `gcloud components update` I was able to deploy my application normally without any problems.